# Unity-Breakout Game with a Healthbar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a breakout game, and I wanted to add a healthbar that decreases when the ball touches a certain object with the tag "hazard". I have a Game Manager Script, and A Pickup interact script, but with the way I set it up, I'm kind of confused with how to trigger takedamage from my GM script to my pickup script, considering I put my playerhealth elements into my GM script, so I can attach it to empty gameobject call Game Manager, since the actual player isnt in the hierarchy, but instantiated during runtime.  I'm hoping I don't have to redo the whole thing just for this purpose. If someone could help me figure this out, I'd appreciate it.

Here's my GM script:

```
public class GM : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int lives = 3;
    public int bricks = 20;
    public float resetDelay = 1f;
    public Text livesText;

    public GameObject gameOver;
    private GameObject clonePaddle;
    public GameObject youWon;
    public GameObject bricksPrefab;
    public GameObject paddle;
    public GameObject deathParticles;
    public static GM instance = null;

    public int startingHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;
    public Slider healthSlider;

    bool isDead;
    bool damaged;



    void Awake()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
        TakeDamage(10);

        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        Setup();

    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        damaged = true;

        currentHealth -= amount;
        healthSlider.value = currentHealth;

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            LoseLife();
        }

    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        clonePaddle = Instantiate(paddle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Instantiate(bricksPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }


    void CheckGameOver()
    {
        if (bricks < 1)
        {
            youWon.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = .25f;
            Invoke("Reset", resetDelay);
        }

        if (lives < 1)
        {
            gameOver.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = .25f;
            Invoke("Reset", resetDelay);
        }

    }

    void Reset()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    public void LoseLife()
    {
        lives--;
        livesText.text = "Lives: " + lives;
        Instantiate(deathParticles, clonePaddle.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(clonePaddle);
        Invoke("SetupPaddle", resetDelay);
        CheckGameOver();
    }

    void SetupPaddle()
    {
        clonePaddle = Instantiate(paddle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    public void DestroyBrick()
    {
        bricks--;
        CheckGameOver();
    }
}
```

And here's my Pickup Script:

```
public class Pickups : MonoBehaviour {

    public float PaddleSpeedValue = 0.5f;

    private bool isActive = false;

    public float thrust=20f;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    GameObject player;



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
         if (other.tag == "Hazard")
        {
            isActive = true;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you block-select an entire block of text in the question editor and press Ctrl+K, the editor will indent the entire text by four spaces, thus formatting it as code.

Comment: Or you can just push the code button... It's the one with the `{}` symbol(s). --- Also, just a headsup, that's a pretty naive and error-prone implementation of the `Singleton` pattern for unity. Take a look at the [Singleton implementation reference at the wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton); it's a bit outdated and veteran programmers can make it much better, but it's a good start and already a better implementation than yours.

Answer (score 0):

The `Pickups` class should not have or store a reference to the player at all (although it is not clear from your question if this is a script attached to the player or attached to something else). Your Game Manager class should. Afterall, it is the class that is responsible for *managing the game* which includes the player. From there, you can use `GetComponent<?>()` to access any scripts attached to the player GameObject.

Then as the `GM` contains a public static reference to itself, any other class can get a reference to the player by doing `GM.instance.player` as needed, even if the player is created and destroyed several times (as the GM should always have a reference to the current one!)

Presumably the `clonePaddle` field is the player('s GameObject), all you have to do is make it public.

Comment: Bad advice on "make it public". It's bad practice to make fields that don't need to be public, well, public. Use `[SerializeField]` on a **`private`** field with a `public` ***property*** to handle access to/from external scripts instead. --- Would deserve a +1, if it wasn't for that. --- Could also have explained `Singleton`, and warned about how OP's implementation is naive and error-prone, but that's off topic in regards to the actual question, so meh.